# EmberJS: Computed property with get/set rendered in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is a reduced version of my code but it still illustrates the issue I'm having. I'm trying to bind the computed property value with textValue.

Please note, that I know I can just do the basic as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smdHH/1/) but this does not meet my needs.

In the large version of this code, not illustrated here, I perform modifications to `value` before setting and modification to `text` after getting. That's the gist of why I can't just use the default binding illustrated in the above fiddle.

**JS**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    text: "Default",
    textValue: function(key, value) {
        if(arguments.length === 1) {
            return this.get('text');
        } else {
            this.set('text', value);
        }
    }.property('text')
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{input value=textValue}}
    <br>   
    TextValue: {{textValue}}
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EW7xD/1/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required to return a value for your computed property

http://jsfiddle.net/EW7xD/2/

**js**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    text: "Default",
    textValue: function(key, value) {
        if(arguments.length === 1) {
            return this.get('text');
        } else {
            this.set('text', value);
            return this.get('text');
        }
    }.property('text')
});
```

or maybe simplify it

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    text: "Default",
    textValue: function(key, value) {
        if(arguments.length > 1) {
            this.set('text', value);
        } 
        return this.get('text');
    }.property('text')
});
```

Comment: The long day strikes again! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As of Ember.js 1.12, checking of arguments length is deprecated, since the discrete setter/getters for computed properties has been adopted.

```
textValue: Ember.computed('text',  {
    get() {
      return this.get('text');
    },
    set(value) {
      this.set('text', value);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Hi, I think there's a problem with this synthax. The following worked for me: textValue: Ember.computed('text',  {
    get: function() {
      return this.get('text');
    },
    set: function(key, value, rawValue) {
      this.set('text', value);
    }
  })

Comment: Ember uses a ES6 transpiler; thus `function` keyword is not mandatory.  [Example here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20sayHello()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('Hello')%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0Afoo.sayHello()%3B)

Comment: Uh... sure, but that's still not valid syntax. Nix the colon, add prens if you want to do function member shorthand. Should be `get() {return this.get('text')},`